# Inherit product save method

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I would like to run a script when a product is saved (added or updated).

Following the advice of the answer to [this thread](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/run-python-script-on-product-save-24531), I created and installed a module and tried to override the save method of product.product, like so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp.osv import osv

class lcd_update(osv.osv):
  _inherit = 'product.product'

  def save(self, **args):
    self.log()
    value = super(lcd_update, self).save(self, **args)
    return value

  def log():
    f = open('log.txt', 'w')
    f.write('test\n')
    f.close()
```

To be honest, I don't know whether `lcd_update` is correct here. I followed this from the documentation.

What's wrong with this code? It isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following and add your custom code either before to the return statement or catch the result of super somewhere and add your code after that and return the changed result, do not forget to return from the method.

```
from openerp.osv import osv

class lcd_update(osv.osv):
  _inherit = 'product.product'

  def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    return super(lcd_update,self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

  def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    return super(lcd_update,self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Well, that did the job! Thank you very much :)!